# IR Thermometer Design

Tags: infrared, photodiode

I'm working on an IR contact-less thermometer. I am using [Diana Friedman's paper](http://www.ee.washington.edu/people/faculty/darling/ee533w12/PastProjects/EE533Project_DianaFriedman.pdf) as a general guide. I'm planning on using a circuit similar to the one presented in figure 10.

I'm planning on using the [SFH 203 FA](http://catalog.osram-os.com/media/_en/Graphics/00042862_0.pdf) photodiode which senses in the near infrared range and has a fairly small half angle. It also has a built-in light filter.

I'm expecting very small leakage currents (on the order of `nA`'s) that I'll have to measure. In Diana's design, she's using the [OPA380](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa380.pdf) amplifier which is marketed as a "transimpedance amplifier" ideally suited for this type of application. Unfortunately, this is only sold in SMD packages and what I'd really like is a through-hole component.

I'm considering using the [TC7650](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21463b.pdf) chopper amplifier instead. It has better current input bias and voltage input offset characteristics than the OPA380, but also has a significantly smaller gain-bandwidth product (`2MHz` vs. `90MHz`).

I expect this means that my maximum sampling frequency will be `1/45` that of the original circuit, but I'm not sure how to calculate the gain for the circuit so I have no idea if this is an acceptable sacrifice for my uses.

1. How do I calculate the gain of the circuit in figure 10, or more directly the maximum sampling rate for the same circuit?
2. Are there other parameters about the amplifiers I need to take into consideration? As far as I can tell I've mentioned the 3 big ones already.

Answer (score 1):

First comment is that, based on Figure 4, this setup is simply measuring the temperature of the diode, not the temperature of a blackbody radiator based on IR radiation. (Figure 4 appears to show the heat pack in contact with the diode.) Further, blackbody radiation at the temperatures referenced in the paper peak at much longer wavelengths than the cutoff of silicon diodes (about 1100 nm.)

Second comment regarding the gain: The simple model for a photodiode is an ideal current source in parallel with a capacitor. For a transimpedance amplifier as shown, neglect the diode capacitance since is is shorted to virtual ground. The feedback network is 10 meg in parallel with 0.51 nF, which gives a pole in the transfer function at \$\dfrac{\pi \times R \times C}{2}\$ or roughly 49 kHz. This really says nothing about the sampling rate, it's just how the current from the diode is going to be translated to a voltage by the transimpedance circuit. The sampling rate is set by the A/D converter.

Third comment: these amplifiers have high enough gain-bandwidth to be considered ideal for all practical purposes for this circuit. You can do an exact transfer function but a 10% capacitor tolerance would swamp out the non-ideal effects of the amplifier.

Bottom line though, is that this setup is simply measuring the temperature of the diode. It is not measuring temperature via IR response. You can get a much more accurate tempeature sensor from TI, Analog Devices, National, etc. that is integrated on a single chip. Or you can just measure the leakage current of a diode to do the same thing.

Comment: Very first sentence: `A device that measures the infrared emitted by an item using a photodiode, and then converts the measured infrared to a temperature reading.` And there is IR radiation emitted below 1100 nm at room temperature, it's just very small compared to longer wavelengths.

Comment: If you read the entire report you will see that this sentence is mistaken, the project measures the resistance of the diode itself. If you want a contactless thermometer you need to be sensing in the 8 to 12 micron range.